# Can't start app due to onCreate error

Tags: android

I just made a simple app, and I don't know why but it can't start, when I open the app it just shuts down and the log cat says that there is an error on line 70 that is `super.onCreate`, I have another app that has the same onCreate method and it just starts perfectly

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

here is the log cat:

```
04-08 00:33:09.645: I/ActivityManager(532): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes/.MainActivity} from pid 787
04-08 00:33:09.716: I/ActivityManager(532): Start proc com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes for activity com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes/.MainActivity: pid=4432 uid=10139 gids={50139, 1028}
04-08 00:33:09.747: I/BufferQueue(142): [Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes](this:0x4281a208,api:0) setConsumerName: Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes
04-08 00:33:09.757: I/BufferQueue(142): [Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes](this:0x4281a208,api:0) setDefaultBufferSize: w=480, h=854
04-08 00:33:09.793: I/BufferQueue(142): [Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes](this:0x4281a208,api:0) connect: api=2
04-08 00:33:09.793: I/BufferQueue(142): [Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes](this:0x4281a208,api:2) setSynchronousMode: enabled=1
04-08 00:33:09.793: I/BufferQueue(142): [Starting com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes](this:0x4281a208,api:2) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-08 00:33:09.874: D/dalvikvm(4432): open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes-2.apk@classes.dex
04-08 00:33:09.937: W/System.err(4432):     at com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
04-08 00:33:09.941: E/AndroidRuntime(4432):     at com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
04-08 00:33:09.944: W/ActivityManager(532):   Force finishing activity com.luisalmeida.geradorchaveseuromilhoes/.MainActivity
```

Comment: And what is the error? Post the logcat.

Comment: @SimonSays can that kind of error result in errors in my fragment_main.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call getSupportFragmentManager your class must extends FragmentActivity